# How do you remove the metadata redirect in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I have ServiceStack installed via NuGet, and I have added the following Config within SetConfig:

```
EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Metadata)
```

which has removed the physical page from /metadata however, each time I try to hit the root, I am still redirected to /metadata. I could not see anything else allowing me to handle this on the official page ( https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page ) - any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own Default.html/.cshtml/etc home page for your services or you can specify the in the `DefaultRedirectPath` or `MetadataRedirectPath` in the [EndpointHostConfig](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/EndpointHostConfig.cs#L344-345).

Comment: Cheers @mythz, I didn't think to check for a redirect path, I simply assumed if by turning the metadata off, the redirect would turn off as well.

Comment: The working link is: https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStack.Contrib/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.MonoTouch/EndpointHostConfig.cs

Answer (score 1):

```
    SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
        EnableFeatures = Feature.All
                                   .Remove(Feature.Metadata)
                                 //.Remove(Feature.PredefinedRoutes)
                                 //.Add(Feature.ProtoBuf)
                                 //... and more
                                   ,
        DefaultRedirectPath = "/default", //set default|index|home
      //... and more
    });
```