# Replace metadata page to Aspx page in Servicestack?

Tags: service, servicestack

I want to replace metadata page of servicestack to my custom design page. I have already tried to customise the metadata page but we want to replace our aspx page. In that Aspx page we want to add/remove our plugins of servicestack.

We are using servicestack `version 3.9` for development.

1. How we can replace `/metadata` page to other page?
2. If replacement of page is possible then how I can access MetadataFeature handler? means, How I can display all Operations in that page?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344149/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-servicestack-metadata-page ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked this post. But this post is about customization of metadata page. I want to replace metadata page to my page.

Comment: Try [setting the `MetadataRedirectPath` in EndpointHostConfig][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887034/how-do-you-remove-the-metadata-redirect-in-servicestack

Comment: Thanks for question one answer. How we can access Metadata Feature Handler in that page?